# Trying to display a Tree

Tags: java, tree

I'm in the middle of writing a program that could display a family tree where children are to the left and their sibling are to the right. Such a tree would look like the following:

```
                              gradfather
                             /       \
                            child     gradfathers sibling
                           /    \
               childs child      childs first sibling
                                  \
                                   childs second sibling etc
```

I know it may be a little weird but I'm trying to practice graphs.  Anyway, I'm trying to write a method that could display the tree and I'm not quite sure if my logic is correct.  My code is as follows

```
public void printTree() {
    Node current = root;
    Node parent;
    while (current.left != null) {
        System.out.print("Great-Great Gradfather is: " + root);
        current = current.left;
        parent = current;
        if (current.right != null) {
            System.out.print("His children are: ");
            while (current.right != null) {
                System.out.print(current + " ");
                current = current.right;
            }
        }
        current = parent;
        current = current.left;
        parent = current;
    }
}
```

The output I am looking to get would be

```
your Great grandfather was name

his children were names

they're children were names

your siblings are names
```

would it be more efficient to write a more simple print function that displays the 'current' root at the time and just the siblings, and in my main do a `System.out.print` saying "their children are" and then printing.  Like maybe iterate the current to `current.left` everytime?  Or am I on the right track with one large print method?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Not sure I understand the purpose of a *binary* tree here. Siblings should go left-right. Children and parents go up-down

Comment: @cricket_007 yes I had that same conversation with my teacher, although I feel like she wants to make it more difficult going this way...

Comment: sorry for the OT, but this is a really weird family tree. Why would you not try to implement a more traditional looking one?

Comment: IMO, a better way to print this would be just like a filesystem listing. https://askubuntu.com/questions/431251/how-to-print-the-directory-tree-in-terminal?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @LonelyNeuron unfortunately, this is how my teacher told us to do it.  I suggested doing it the more logical way, but she wanted it this way.

Comment: do you actually want to print it like you showed at the top of your post, or is this just to illustrate the tree?

Comment: Please do [edit] your post to include the output you do want. For example, are you printing all children or all siblings first?

Comment: How would you like to print out given the above example?

Comment: Ok I just edited it, sorry should have thought about that before

Comment: I am still confused by your code. You print the grandfathers `Node` in each iteration. Also: Do you know in advance how big the tree will be? What if it starts with 100 generations back? don't you need to add `"great"` to the output `String` in a loop? What about children of `sibling 1`, `sibling 2`, etc..? do you want to print them too?

Comment: First of all your family tree is not correct. You have a sibling under sibling which is false. Second what i understood so far => use breadth first search and print things from top to bottom.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim read through the past comments. This is meant to be. First child goes left, all siblings go right. It works, it's just weird

Comment: @IanMcMahon also, please answer to people using @.., or they won't be notified, meaning nobody will answer you ;)

Comment: @LonelyNeuron hey man!  sorry i got really busy and wasn't able to respond.  That's where I was getting a little confused.  The root is supposed to be the great-great grandfather, so no matter what there will be four generations, with unlimited siblings.  Believe me, no one is more confused about why it's structured like this then me.  I actually had one written out and finished the way it 'should' be but this threw an ugly left handed monkey wrench in it.  What I was thinking was just making a simple iteration print, which prints the parent, and all the 'siblings' to the right, and just

Comment: @LonelyNeuron manually type an output in the main for what the relation is, as in great-great, or just grandpa/grandma, I'm just not sure if that would make the most sense

Comment: @IanMcMahon I won't be able to write a proper answer within the next day or so. What I would do is create 4 Sets, representing the 4 generations. Then iterate through your tree and count the amounts you took the left branch. the amount of times you took the left branch is your generation. Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Note: each **"sibbling"** should be at **"the same level in the tree"** !